# _NULL_ preventing overwriting table?

Tags: sas

I have come across a scenario where *NULL* may be preventing datastep to execute.
Can someone please have a look and confirm why is this happening.

Ran this in SAS EG :

```
/*create a TEMP1 table*/
data TEMP1;
input Name $ age score;
cards;
A 10 100
B .  20
C 20 .
D .  .
;
run;

/* step to overwrite WORK.TEMP1 dots with 0 */
DATa _NULL_;
SET TEMP1;
file print;
array a1 _numeric_;
do over a1;
if a1=. then a1=0;
end;
run;
```

Expectation is that all numeric fields with dot to be overwritten with 0.

It does only when DATA *NULL* is replaced with DATA TEMP1

A bit of a conundrum.

Comment: You don't have any way to tell whether the values were changed or not since you are neither writing them to an output dataset nor using a PUT statement to write them to listing.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different ways to replace values in an existing table

- overwriting the entire table with a new copy of itself

  - `data name; set name; …`
- modifying values in-place within existing table

  - `data name; modify name; …`

Example

```
1    data class;
2      set sashelp.class;
3    run;

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.CLASS has 19 observations and 5 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.17 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


4
5    data class;     /* output data set named is same as input data set */
6      set class;
7      age = age * 2;
8    run;

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set WORK.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.CLASS has 19 observations and 5 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds


9
10   data class;      /* output data set name */
11     modify class;  /* is same as modify name, values updated in place */  
12     age = age / 2;
13   run;             /* observations are rewritten (see log) */

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set WORK.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.CLASS has been updated.  There were 19 observations rewritten, 0
      observations added and 0 observations deleted.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.05 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

A third way would be to use SQL `UPDATE` statement with sets based on `coalesce`, however, that is not amenable to array processing.

```
Proc SQL;
  update mydata set 
    a1 = coalesce (a1,0)
  , s2 = coalesce (a2,0)
  … 
  ;
```

Comment: good, wonder if it should be caveated somewhat (ie, within a datastep, and two 'typical' ways - as there are also 'alternative' ways to update dataset values!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some comments that may help. Basically, as others have indicated, `_NULL_` does not create an output data set so your assumption there is incorrect.

You're also using FILE incorrectly I suspect but don't know what you're trying to do with that statement.

You also are using a DO OVER loop which is deprecated as of SAS V7 so you shouldn't use it in production code.

```
DATa _NULL_;*_Null_ means no output data set is created;

SET TEMP1; *input data set means temp1;

file print; *writes to a file named print, no filename statement so no idea what this means to you;

array a1 _numeric_; *creates an array of all numeric values;

 do over a1; *Do over is deprecated as of 20 years ago, it works but I don't recommend using it in production code;
             if a1=. then a1=0; *replaces missing with 0;
end;*ends loop;

*no put statements so nothing is written the file print;

run;
```

You could fix it by doing this, but I don't recommend using the same data set name. It makes it hard to debug your code later on.

```
/* step to overwrite WORK.TEMP1 dots with 0 */
DATa TEMP1;
SET TEMP1;
array a1 _numeric_;
do over a1;
if a1=. then a1=0;
end;
run;
```

Comment: `PRINT` is the name of the standard output for SAS code/procedures. Using `file print;` means that results of `put` statements will go to the listing output instead of the log.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `data _NULL_` instead of `data temp1` you only read from temp1 but you changes will be written nowhere. That is not conundrum that is basic SAS functionality. Only use `_NULL_` when you don't need data to be written.

Comment: thanks; I was in the impression _NULL_ does not create a dataset but allows actions within to be executed

Comment: The actions will be executed but they have no effect in your case. For example you could print output to LOG with PUT.